# Post serialized form data and extra variables using JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this piece of code to serialize a form AND send an extra variable not found in the form, at the same time. The following line of code is what I expected, but sadly does not work.

```
var thePage = theFilename();
$.post("pagedetail.php", { $("#PageDetailForm").serialize(), thePage: thePage },
    function(data) {
        alert(data); 
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    var serialized = $('#PageDetailForm').serialize();
    serialized.thePage = thePage;

    $.post("pagedetail.php", serialized,
    function(data) {
        alert(data); 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add thePage onto the end of the form values. My Print_R in PHP only shows that the form fields have been submitted :(.

Close though... Any other thoughts???

Comment: Oh... I found this to work:

var serialized = $('#PageDetailForm').serialize() + "&thePage=" + thePage;

Thanks for your help though!!!

Comment: then try adding an <input type="hidden" value="thePageValue" />, it'll be serialized with the rest. @Andy Barlow

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is to add the extra data to an hidden input and catch it in the 
`pagedetail.php` page .

eg lats say your  form

```
   <form id='PageDetailForm'>
   <input type="hidden" name="value"  id="value" value="the value u wamnt to add goes here" />
             ....other inputs
</form>
```

after this just do your normal `$.post`

```
$.post("#pagedetail.php",$("#PageDetailForm").serialize(),function(data){

    $("#ans").html(data);

// in the pagedetail.php

$echo $_POST['value'];
```

hope dis help if ur still confused hola me `@dplumptre`

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the second parameter to `$.post`:

```
 { form: $("#PageDetailForm").serialize(), thePage: thePage }
```

Comment: Sadly, this splits up the data into two arrays. One with Form, with one sting in it, and another with thePage. Nearly there though :)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you still need this :).
Try the serializeArray() method and then push some additional data in the resulting array, so you don't have splitted arrays etc.:

```
var postData = $('#form-id').serializeArray();
var additionalData = $('#additionalDataID').val();
postData.push({name: 'additionalName', value: additionalData});
```

and finally:

```
$.post(URL, postData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sortable('toArray')`:

```
var thePage = theFilename();

$.post("pagedetail.php", { pageDetailForm: $("#PageDetailForm").sortable('toArray'), thePage: thePage },
    function(data) {
        alert(data); 
});
```